# Execute the all iterations of for loop even if some index is undefined (Javascript)(ajax)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

The problem is if for e.g `response[i]` or `response[i][j]` is undefined   the loops execution is stopped and gives this error:

> TypeError: response[i][j] is undefined.

What i want is that all iterations of  for loops  should be executed regardless of an index is defined or not.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= response.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= response.length; j++) {
    //  alert(response.length);
    if (response[i][j]["id"]) {
      html +=
        '<option value="' +
        response[i][j]["id"] +
        '">' +
        response[i][j]["name"] +
        "</option>";
      // alert(response.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much **Yury Tarabanko**  your answer helped alot.. I was actually able to solve my question by

```
             if(response[i] && response[i][j] && response[i][j]['id']){
 html += '<option value="'+response[i][j]['id']+'">'+response[i][j]['name']+'</option>';
 }}}
```

Comment: I had increased the usefulness of your answer but as i have less than 15 reputations it didn't showed publicly .post your answer so that i can make it an accepted answer :) and please don't downgrade mine.